# Prevent application launch if already running

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My app needs to check and see if it is already running when launching so it doesn't open a second time. I have a system tray icon that can make the application visible = False. Works great. However,
I need to make sure the user looks at the system tray for the notifyicon if the app is already running.

```
Private Sub mainWindowSmall_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim p() As Process
        p = Process.GetProcessesByName("TSC Tool Box")
        If p.Count > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("The TSC Tool Box is already running. Check System tray!", _
            "Warning !!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
            MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)
            Me.Close()
        Else
            totalOnLoad()
        End If
    End Sub
```

VB.NET | winforms

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This feature is already built in to Windows Forms. Go to the project properties and click the "Single Instance Application" checkbox. There's also a [StartupNextInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startupnextinstance.aspx) event that you can handle.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicated question. Thank you for the answer @Joel. Exactly what I was looking for.